# RAID1 very slow with LSI card and 2x Samsung EVO 850 drives

Tags: raid, performance, storage

not sure if I'm checking it correctly, but here is what I have.

Desktop, LSI 9260-8i card, see config below. 2x 500Gb Samsung 850 EVO drives.
I also have Samsung 830 drive attached to motherboard directly (bootable with Win7)

So, I run HDTune Pro in Windows 7 to check drive performance. Old drive (system one) gets about 370mbps read speeds.

Virtual drive from controller get's about 120-130mbps. I expected it to be faster. Any ideas why it might be happening?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache on the card is getting in the way. The raid card cache is designed to enhance the performance of spinning drives. The best option on most ssd array is direct io and write through. You can test the different performance using hdtune or various other tools. You can leave the drive cache enabled.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I was trying different stripe sizes, etc. But write through and "direct" were correct settings for SSD.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a desktop system, this will likely get marked as off-topic and redirected to SuperUser - FYI.

More hardware specifications would be needed to answer with any degree of certainty (what motherboard, which PCI slot the card is in, etc).

However, that LSI card may well be the performance bottleneck. I would suggest you set up a single-drive RAID0 and compare performance results through the controller. I've seen reports of similar results with controllers more recently manufactured, as they were not designed with optimization for use with SSDs in mind. This model is from 2009 or earlier, and LSI's 2013 cards were the first I've seen to start to keep up with multiple SSDs.